# ColdFusion Programmer wants to use new version of Java APNS but doesn't know how to compile Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, coldfusion

I'm a ColdFusion programmer. I'm currently using an older version of [notnoop's java APNS library](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns). I originally downloaded the most recent binary (apns-0.1.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar — 0.1.5 release with dependencies) from their [download](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/downloads) page.

I want to upgrade to a newer version of the library, but, there are no pre-compiled binaries of the new versions. So, I'm assuming I will have to compile it myself. I am not familiar with how to compile Java libraries. The [instructions that notnoop gives](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/wiki/installation) for installation are not very informative (I'm sure they are if you're familiar with Java and/or Maven).

Can someone lead me in the right direction as to how to go about compiling this into a JAR that I can use with my ColdFusion applications (how to create the project in Eclipse, include the necessary dependencies, etc., and compile it)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the repository. Go to the correct branch you want to build from.

1. Install apache maven if you don't have it already. [Download Here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. From the terminal - cd to the repository where the `pom.xml` file exists (root level)
3. Run `mvn clean install` to build the jar.

This should create a `mvn_build_products` or `build` or `target` folder where the built Jar will live.

Also worth noting - they have the built jars hosted on their [github site](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/releases).

Answer (score 2):

The link you included tells you that the 0.2.3 version is available on the central maven repository for download by java programs.
You can actually download it manually too.
Go to the central maven repository & search for the exact text in the maven dependency:  com.notnoop.apns

If you do that you will see this page listing the available versions with links to download the various jar files:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.notnoop.apns%22%20AND%20a%3A%22apns%22

You can see there is a jar file & a jar including the various dependencies.